# How to connect to a server made in java?

Tags: java, testing, server

I am trying to connect to a server I made in java,to see wether the server just displays the message or send them to the clients.When I run it in eclipse it seem that I can start the server and clients can connect to it,but I don't know if the message just appear in console or are actually sent tot the users.How can I test the server I made?

EDIT:code for the ClientPeer,TextClient,Server,ServerPeer classes.ServerConfig returns the TCP_PORT key and the MAX_CLIENTS (int).Also ,the method getAll() return the message and who is it coming from.
Now i can start the server and connect a client but in the TextClient it doesn't show anything,though in the sever it does show the messages.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientPeer extends Thread {

    String _username;
    Socket _Socket;

    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_Socket.getInputStream());

            Message _mess = (Message) _ois.readObject();

            System.out.println(_mess.getAll());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public ClientPeer(String _username, Socket _Socket)

    {
        this._username = _username;
        this._Socket = _Socket;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String _message) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
                _Socket.getOutputStream());
        _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
        _obj.flush();

    }

    public void sendMessage(String _message, String _receiver)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
                _Socket.getOutputStream());
        _obj.writeObject(new PrivateMessage(_username, _message, _receiver));
        _obj.flush();
    }
}

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerPeer extends Thread {
    Socket _socket;

    public ServerPeer(Socket _socket) {
        this._socket = _socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
            Message _message;
            while (_socket.isConnected()) {

                _message = (Message) _ois.readObject();
                if (_message instanceof Message) {
                    System.out.println(_message.getAll());
                }
                _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TextClient {
    public TextClient() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException, ConnectException, InterruptedException {

        Socket _socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        System.out.println("Please enter your desired username:");
        Scanner _new = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _inputname = _new.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Success.You can now type your messages!");
        ClientPeer _clientpeer = new ClientPeer(_inputname, _socket);
        Scanner _scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _input = _scan.nextLine();

        while (true) {


            if (!_input.equals("exit")) {
                if (_input.startsWith("/w"))
                    _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input, "username");
                else
                    _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input);

            } else
                break;
            _clientpeer.start();
            _input = _scan.nextLine();
        }
        _clientpeer.start();
    }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {
    static ServerConfig _svconfig = new ServerConfig();

    // final static int _mysocket;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            final int _mysocket = _svconfig.getPORTNumber();
            ServerSocket _serversocket = new ServerSocket(_mysocket);
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber()) {
                Socket _clientsocket = _serversocket.accept();
                i++;
                ServerPeer _serverpeer = new ServerPeer(_clientsocket);
                _serverpeer.start();
            }
            _serversocket.close();

        } catch (MissingKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("You have been disconnected");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Make the clients print out the messages they receive?

Comment: You should show us code and other useful information about your problem. Maybe screenshots or something. Next thing: write in clients console, when something is recieved. If a client does not recieve anything, it will not write anything in console.

Comment: I would expect that you would (1) compile the Java program to get your class files, (2) start up a command shell window, (3) navigate to the folder where your compiled Java classes are located, (4) run the Java class of your server using the java VM the appropriate options. When done, close out the command shell to close out the Java VM and your server.